# How to make search in PHP

Tags: php, search

I have 3 distinct lists of strings. First one contains names of people(from 10 chars to 80 chars long). Second one - room numbers(903, 231 and so on). Last one - group numbers(ABCD-1312, CXVZ-123).

I have a query which is given by a user. Firstly, I tried to search using Levenshtein distance, it didn't work, because whenever user types 3 chars, it gives some room number, even though there is no any digit in query. Then, I tried similar_text(), it worked better, but because people names all have different length, it mostly gives results with shorter names.

Now, the best I come up with is using similar_text() and str_pad() to make each string equal length. Still doesn't work properly.

I want to somehow give extra weight to strings, if they have several matches in a row, or if query and my string starts with the same letter and so on.

```
$search_min_heap = new SearchMinHeap();

$query = strtolower($query);    // similar_text is case sensitive, so make everything lowercase
foreach ($res["result"] as &$item) {
    similar_text($query, str_pad(strtolower($item["name_en"]), 100, " "), $cur_distance_en);
    similar_text($query, str_pad(strtolower($item["name_ru"]), 100, " "), $cur_distance_ru);
    similar_text($query, str_pad(strtolower($item["name_kk"]), 100, " "), $cur_distance_kk);

    $cur_max_distance = max($cur_distance_en, $cur_distance_ru, $cur_distance_kk);
    $item["matching"] = $cur_max_distance;
    $search_min_heap->insert($item);
}

$first_elements = $search_min_heap->getFirstElements($count);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)